# can an Actionscript AS3 app be converted to Adobe AIR using free/cheap tools?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

suppose I have an AS3 app made using FlashDevelop (I don't have the expensive IDE). Now I want to turn it into AIR app to deploy it on mobile or run it on the desktop or whatever. So how do I do that? Is there a free conversion utility? Or would I need to either buy some IDE or else get somebody else with a license do the conversion for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to buy any tools to build for, test on, and deploy to Adobe AIR.  Everything you need is in the free Adobe AIR SDK.

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/sdk/

Comment: He asked if there was a way to convert an AS3 app into an Adobe AIR app. He didn't ask about what the Adobe AIR SDK contains or whether it is free or not.

Comment: @user734063, Please re-read the original question. My answer is exactly what he asked for. He asked if he needs and IDe or a license to convert to an AIR app and I confirmed he did not.

Answer (score 0):

Any Flash content can be packaged with AIR to iOS, Android, and BlackBerry.

From Flash Professional, this can be done by changing the Publish Settings. Refer [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html)